# Angular 6 Firestore: render string embedded with HTML tags ... without displaying tags

Tags: html, angular, string, typescript, wysiwyg

**Angular 6**

**Firestore**

I have a blog `article` object stored in Firestore. I'm using a wysiwyg editor to edit and save `article.content`, which is a string, to the database. When `article.content` is saved, it looks like this:

`"<p>Some content.<p><br><p>More content</p>"`

It renders that way too, un-styled, showing all of the HTML tags.

How do I render this so that the content is styled by the tags and the tags are not displayed?

Here is the code.

```
# article-detail-component.ts

export class ArticleDetailComponent {
  articlesCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<Article>;
  article: any;
  id: any;

  constructor (private route: ActivatedRoute,
               private afs: AngularFirestore) {
      this.articlesCollection = this.afs.collection('articles');
      this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
          this.id = params['id'];
      });
      this.articlesCollection.doc(`${this.id}`).ref.get().then((doc) => {
        this.article = doc.data();
      });
  }
}
```

```
# article-detail-component.html

<app-ngx-editor [(ngModel)]="article.content"></app-ngx-editor>
<hr>
<div>
  {{article.content}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind the data to the `innerHTML` property to render the dynamic HTML in the view:

```
<div [innerHTML]="article.content"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I've been reading about this and struggling with it for about 4 hours. This works perfectly.